# OnRefresh State Persist which contains 100s of images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, web-deployment

How to persists the state with lots of images when the user reloads or refreshes the page?

for example:

Suppose a React webpage makes a request and renders lots of images (say 100), Now if the user refreshes the page we don't want to make the API call. So how can we achieve this?

This question was asked in an interview and I'm really struggling with this. Please give a brief explanation, if possible. Thanks

My answer to the interviewer was that we can store in the local storage, but the data is too much.

Can we do this without using any library? If not,
Can we use redux or any state management library for this

And how about the same problem in mobile devices which are built on react-native?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to do it with local storage or cookies.

For example, you mentioned Redux. You could store the images in your redux state and use redux persist so that the data will hold over a refresh.

This doesn't sound like a great practice to me however, you'd be cluttering the user's computer with images, which are significantly sized files.

I could be wrong here or missing a better solution, let me know!

Comment: I was thinking the same. Is there any way so that we don't have to clutter the user's computer?

Comment: I don't believe so. You need to store X amount of data in the user's local storage and there isn't really a way around that.

Comment: @AmitDhaterwal An update. This isn't something you need to implement on most modern browsers because the browser takes care of this for us with HTTP caching: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching. (I think this means your images need to be retrieved using separate HTTP requests)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that. Does this request is same as when we provide src attribute to image?

Comment: Basically if there is an HTTP request to get data, caching can work on that when that request is repeated. So if your img has a source that links to an internal or external url, then the bowser can cache it.

Open up DevTools, go to Network, and then refresh this page. You'll see some of the requests return images and that is what your browser will cache. Keep in mind I'm not an expert on this so do research to learn more if you want.